# Changing queryset on a ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, forms

I have a question about using different querysets with django forms.

So I have a form that requires the user to select an option from the first dropdown, which will change what the queryset on the other dropdown will be.

```
class TransportForm(myformclass):
    trans_type_choices = ['car', 'bus', 'plane', 'train'] 
    trans_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=model_type_choices, label='Select the model you wish to change')
    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Label.objects.none(), label='Choose a model')
```

My form is using ajax to do the correct query and return the values; I do not want to have separate fields as the query count would be too high.

My problem is that, when I then submit the form, the queryset is wrong for the validation. Should I override the form validation somehow and stop this from happening?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that django `ModelChoiceField` uses the `queryset` to store all possible choices. If you change your front end code to pass in an `id` that isn't in the `queryset`, django would fail your validation.

An easy solution would be to just use `Label.objects.all()` as the queryset for `ModelChoiceField`, but change the front end based on what the other choice is. If you concern about security, you can write your own validation to double check on the correlation between `trans_type` and `model`.